# MATLAB char to cell array

Tags: matlab, char, double

I have to following char in Matlab:

```
charList = '{''68'', ''10''}'
```

(I actually don't create this one in Matlab, this is coming from .NET but to make this example I just created it...)

Right now I want to do this:

```
cellArray = str2double(charList)
```

Outcome is 'NaN'.. because this is just a char. Is it possible to create a char array just from a char which has already the correct syntax?

e.g. something like char2cellArray?

Thanks!

Comment: I am confused, is this MATLAB or C#?

Comment: @maccettura Definitely MATLAB. I'm removing the C# tag.

Comment: This looks like an array that is encoded in a string.  Simplest way is to use `eval` combined with `str2double` (*gasp*).  `cellArray = str2double(eval(charList));`.  I'm not writing this as a formal answer because any answer with `eval` sucks.  It would help if you gave us more insight as to how `charList` is generated.  Is it possible to generate it in another way?

Comment: Depending on the specific format of the incoming data you can use a regular expression. For example `result = regexp(charList,'\d+','match')` or `result = str2double(regexp(charList,'\d+','match'))`

Comment: @LuisMendo I just finished writing that answer when you put in that comment.

Comment: @rayryeng Alike minds think great :-D

Comment: @rayryeng the charList is created by User input. Which means we can change it in case another way would be easier to evaluate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach is to use [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) and use the [`'Whitespace'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#btghhyz-1-Whitespace) parameter to filter out the undesired characters.

For example:

```
charList = '{''68'', ''10'', ''1.234'', ''-15'', ''-1.234''}';

nums = textscan(charList, '%f', 'Whitespace', '{} \b\t''', 'Delimiter', ',', 'CollectOutput', true);
nums = [nums{:}];  % Denest the double array from the cell
```

Which gives us:

```
>> nums

nums =

   68.0000
   10.0000
    1.2340
  -15.0000
   -1.2340
```

Comment: Since the `charList` is user input we don't need to have the undesired characters in the first place. I will make easier to this: `char = '1 2 3 4 5 6'`  and use the textscan method. Thanks!

Comment: what would be the syntax if i want to have a 1x5 double instead of a 5x1 double? @excaza

Comment: [`transpose`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html), or `.'`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to use `eval` on that string because the cell array is encoded in the string.  I would however not recommend this approach as `eval` is not only unsafe, but no code optimization is performed when running any code in `eval`:

```
cellArray = str2double(eval(charList));
```

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions to extract any numbers that appear and convert that into an array:

```
cellArray = str2double(regexp(charList, '-?\d+\.?\d*', 'match'));
```

The regular expression allows floating point numbers to be extracted, rather than just integers.  In addition, negative values can be extracted.

Comment: `(\d+\.?\d*)` would probably be a better regex to accommodate floats.

Comment: Or `-?\d+\.?\d*`

Comment: @excaza definitely. I'll edit when I'm able. About to go into a meeting.

Comment: Works perfectly! But since I can make the `charList` easier and remove those characters I thought it might help, I rather choose the textscan method since it's a lot easier than regex :D